# Drag and drop files only in specific regions?

Tags: jquery, html

When I try to use examples of drag and drop for file uploads like [this](https://css-tricks.com/examples/DragAndDropFileUploading/),
if I drop the file outside the region in firefox it opens the file. Is there a way to limit dragging and dropping only to certain regions? I know that there's a related question where I can disable dragging and dropping on the entire page but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is opening the file due to a property of firefox, in which if a file is dragged into it and there is no such associated action, it is simply opened in browser. There isn't any code you can add to prevent this, as it doesn't actually have anything to do with your web page. This is actually the case for most browsers. What I would do instead is make the entire screen a zone in which you can drag a file. That way, no matter where the user puts it, you are receiving the file.